# How to sort a table based off every other row using straight javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-table

I am trying to sort a table that has a data row with multiple fields followed by data row related to the previous row but is a long data field that spans all columns.

It worked great until I had to add the extra data row in between the other rows.

I tried changing the increment and moving around but I can't quite put my finger on the logic to sort through every other row and then move that row (data sort row) AND the following row (expanded data row) at the same time.

Basic table layout

```
<table class="tableCSS" id="myTable" padding="1" spacing="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th onclick="sortTable(0)"><u>Field 1</u></th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(1)"><u>Field 1</u></th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(2)"><u>Field 1</u></th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(3)"><u>Field 1</u></th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(4)"><u>Field 1</u></th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(5)"><u>Field 1</u></th>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Data1-1</td>
        <td>Data1-2</td>
        <td>Data1-3</td>
        <td>Data1-4</td>
        <td>Data1-5</td>
        <td>Data1-6</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Long formatted data 1</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Data2-1</td>
        <td>Data2-2</td>
        <td>Data2-3</td>
        <td>Data2-4</td>
        <td>Data2-5</td>
        <td>Data2-6</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Long formatted data 2</td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Sort function

```
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 2); i += 2) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 2].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 2], rows[i]);
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 2], rows[i+1]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I've gotten different results with different iterations of the code, but if it does sort, it seems to put the expanded data row before or after or somewhere else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same issue as you and looked around for a solution, found one!

Put each tr:s that you want to stay together in a tbody then change in your sort function from  rows = table.rows; to  rows = table.tbodies

also you might want to change the innerHTMLs to innerText to make sure the sorting is made on the content rather than on the HTML-tags.

Thats it! :)